# JSP <f:validator> didn't see my validation class

Tags: java, validation, jsp

........ ............ ........... ............ ................

My application doesn't display the validated data and I didn't know why.
In other cases it works but not this time, and I really didn't know what's the matter.

**JSP:**

```
(...)

                <div id="contentarea">
                    <c:if test="${userBean.isOnline}">
                        <h2>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.vehicleRegistration}" />
                        </h2>

                        <fieldset>
                            <h:form>
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.brandLabel}" />
                                <h:inputText id="brand" value="#{carBean.brand}">
                                    <f:validator validatorId="TextValidator" />
                                </h:inputText>
                                <h:message for="brand" style="color:red" />
                                <br />


                                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.surnameLabel}" />
                                <h:inputText id="surname" value="#{carBean.surname}">
                                    <f:validator validatorId="TextValidator" />
                                </h:inputText>
                                <h:message for="surname" style="color:red" />
                                <br />

                                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.addresLabel}" />
                                <h:inputText id="address" value="#{carBean.adress}">
                                    <f:validator validatorId="TextValidator" />
                                </h:inputText>
                                <br />
                                <h:message for="address" style="color:red" />
                                <br />

                                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.yearLabel}" />
                                <h:inputText id="year" value="#{carBean.year}">

                                    <f:validator validatorId="NumberValidator" />
                                </h:inputText>
                                <h:message for="year" style="color:red" />
                                <br />
                                <br />

                                <h:commandButton value="#{msg.addButtonLabel}" onclick="alert('#{msg.vehicleAdded}')"
                                    action="#{carList.addToList(carBean)}" styleClass="myButton" />

                            </h:form>
                        </fieldset>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${!userBean.isOnline}">
                        <h2>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.accessDenied}" />
                        </h2>

                        <b><a href="/Project"> <h:outputText
                                    value="#{msg.accessDeniedLabel}" />
                        </a> </b>

                    </c:if>
                </div> 
(...)

</html>
```

**TextValidator.java**

```
package my.jsf.code;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;


public class TextValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        String localePL = facesContext.getViewRoot().getLocale()
                .toLanguageTag();
        String text = localePL.equals("pl") ? "Pole nie może być puste!"
                : "Field cannot be empty!";

        String val = (String) value;


        if (val == null) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(text);
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }

}
```